# Implementing SSO through Office365 in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, single-sign-on, office365, azure-active-directory, identity-management

I am creating a foundation for an expandable Intranet-Application with Ruby on Rails. One of the first tasks given to me was finding a way to implement a User-Sign-In functionality through the company's Office365 account. I've researched this one quite a bit, but would be grateful if someone would point me in the right direction.

I've been reading on about the WS-Federation-Protocol and I have found out that there is a MS Active Directory underlying the whole system, but have not figured out a way to connect to latter.

Any tipps or gem recommendations ?

Answer (score 2):

In order to authenticate with Office365 your application needs to talk WS-Federation protocol with SAML tokens.

I am not familiar with ruby but as far as I can tell there is an omniauth gem called [omniauth-wsfed](https://github.com/kbeckman/omniauth-wsfed).

[passport-wsfed-saml2](https://github.com/auth0/passport-wsfed-saml2) is a module for node.js that we use and we know it works with WAAD and Office365.

The second approach will be to use an authentication broker.

**Disclaimer I work for Auth0.**

[Auth0](http://auth0.com) is an authentication broker, we provide an omniauth gem for ruby that speaks oauth with Auth0, and from our dashboard you just enable your **Office365** Connection.

Comment: Hello José, thank your for your information. I looked into the Auth0 solution. To connect to Office365 it seems that Auth0 needs Client IDs generated by the Seller Dashboard. I'am not sure how that makes sense.  Why would we register for the seller-dashboard if the application is for internal use only? THx

Comment: Despite the misleading "Seller" word on it, it doesn't matter if is internally or every one can use it. You have to identify your application in microsoft in order to allow user authentication from there. It is the same case if you create an internal application that uses google-oauth, you have to register your application in google. If you have more question please come talk with us at chat.auth0.com